# Calling another method from Cocos2d Hud layer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I have two class files hudlayer.m and actionlayer.m

I have a method named **jump in hudlayer.m**
And i have a method named **jumpone in actionlayer.m**

```
-(void) jumpone {
    _heroBody->ApplyLinearImpulse(b2Vec2(_playerVelX/[_lhelper pixelsToMeterRatio], 1.25), _heroBody->GetWorldCenter()); 
}
```

and another method called jump in hudlayer.m

```
-(void)jump {
   ActionLayer *aob = [[ActionLayer alloc] init]; 
   [aob jumpone];
}
```

The problem is when i call the Jumpone method from **actionlayer.m** my sprite jumps (i.e method called)

My init method of action layer

```
- (id)initWithHUD:(HUDLayer *)hud
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {

        [self setupWorld]; 
    }
    return self;
}
```

But when i call **jumpone via jump method in from hudlayer.m** it fails and my app crashed.
Any help will be appreciated .thanks

Comment: Can you post the init method of ActionLayer ? and some traces from the error ?

Comment: I have updated the init method

Comment: ok... lets see the entire initialization ... :). Hey and what happend to jumpone call in the jump method ?

Comment: sorry edited wrongly,,,check now :)

Comment: Can you also post how you create your world objects and bodies ? and the error messages ?

Comment: no error,,it comes to box2d source file...and i created bodies using level helper

Comment: Well its not clear than what exactly going on there but why do you create an entire layer for just jumping ??? in hud layer you should have a pointer to an already initialized action layer and just call the jumpone method with no initialization

Comment: My scene is parallax...so i can't use a button in action layer scene.

Comment: Still it is hard to figure what exactly is going on without some relevant code posted , specially scene/layer initialization and logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best solution for your problem is to add a tag to hudlayer & action layer

ex: hudlayer.tag=1;
actionlayer.tag=2;

and then just use `getChildByTag` like this:

```
[[[[CCDirector sharedDirector]runningScene] getChildByTag:1]jumpone];
```

Comment: Hi thanks for reply...but if i add HUDLayer.tag = 2; i get an error "property tag not found on object of HUDlayer"

Comment: well not HUDLayer.tag literally...i ment add self.tag in hud layer init method...i should've been more specific

Comment: Thanks a lot bro its working now :) bro can i get your Skype ?

Comment: well..funny thing..i dont have skype =) but you can contact me through email (see profile)

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you call jump it creates a new instance of you ActionLayer. And following that, you setup a new world and everything get tangled up. Furthermore its a memory leak.

Make you ActionLayer to an iVar of HUDLayer and call

```
   aob = [[ActionLayer alloc] init];
```

in the HUDs init method. 
Dont forget to release aob in dealloc of the HUDLayer